# Regex to Limit Input To Only Numeric Values To 10 Occurences

Tags: regex

I need help forming regex to limit user input to only numerics and only up to 10 occurrences.

I have regex that is working to keep input to numerics only, but I cannot limit it to up to 10.

Here is what I have:

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

I am okay accepting negative numbers, decimals, and 0's. Any advice?

Comment: Quick edit/addition: I did add some occurrence delimiters {} such as `^(0|[1-9][0-9]*){1,10}$` but that is not working.

Comment: How should they be delimited?

Comment: What's the context for this? HTML input forms?  Bash command line?

Comment: HTML input forms. And @LevLevitsky I do not need them delimited, I was trying to say I added curly braces to denote occurrence delimiters (at least 1, at most 10) but it is not working.

Comment: In your case space is a delimiter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^\s*([0-9)+){0,10}\s*$
```

This basically says I want to 0 to 10 things, where each thing is all digits.  I added the \s* on either side to allow the user to have put spaces before or after their numbers.  This would accept things like

10 1231231 1231  1231 23112  123123

If what you really want is just a single number, that is only up to 10 digits, it is even easier:

```
^\s[0-9]{1,10}\s$
```

Comment: No problem.    I forgot my *'s after the 2 \s's... don't you forget them :)

Comment: Another developer caught it, I would not have. Thanks for the follow up though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
^(?<=\s)(\-?[\d]{1,10}(?=\s))$
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you're looking for is this:

```
/(?=^[-+]?\d*\.?\d+$)^.{1,10}$/
```

Keep in mind that this regex will allow maximum length of input to 10 which includes optional `+` or `-` sign at start and a decimal point `.`.

Answer (score 0):

This fails as it has 11 digits

```
Debug.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("12345678901", @"^\d{1,10}$").ToString());
```

Posted the above answer before you clarified you want up to 10 set of numbers delimited by space.

Tested the accepted answer and in .NET Regex it fails for me.
Even fixing the syntax error it still does not parse by space

Give this a try

```
Debug.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(" 12345 678901 12   ", @"^\s*([+-]?\d+)(\s+[+-]?\d+){1,9}\s*$").ToString());
```